# Laravel 502 bad gateway in Ubuntu LEMP stack

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I can't access my laravel project

My laravel project in /var/www

And i updated nginx in this way:

```
 server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/laravel/public;

    index index.php  index.html index.htm;

    server_name dev-localserve.co;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

How can i fix this problem ?

Comment: Check `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: It says "directory index of var/www/html is forbidden

Comment: Then the user nginx process is running under, has no permissions on that folder, add them.

Comment: How can i add permissions ? Sorry i am new in ubuntu :(

Comment: You should give a proper look into permissions, and what permissions you need. Something like, which user is nginx running under? Is there a group with permissions on that folder? Is the 'nginx' a member of said group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's Ubuntu repository, I believe you have `www-data` user. Run these 2 commands:

```
// For setting ownership
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/laravel

// For setting permissions
chmod 775 -R /var/www/laravel
```

Also, I think your nginx configs may need a bit more:

```
location ~ \.php$ { 
       try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
       #fastcgi_read_timeout 1800; // this line maybe
}
```

Comment: Thank you but now i am getting error 403 forbidden.

Comment: Check your log in `/var/log/nginx/`